# Source tree - fatal: A branch named 'main' already exists when check out

Tags: version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I accidentally commit my local changes to main branch.
Since there is branch protecting setting on main branch, the commit is failed to push to the remote.

But now I am 2 ahead on main.
[image]

When I try to checkout to the `origin/main`, error shows
[image]
[image]

How can I fix it on SourceTree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fix it by

Right click on the commit in the latest `origin/main` > Reset current branch to this commit > Done

Comment: This solves your problem of getting `main` back to how it was, but doesn't solve your problem of putting the commits you made onto another branch like you originally intended. That's easy to do, but I mention it because perhaps that should go before your last "Done" step. ;)